# Append New Element in XML VB or C#

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, vb.net

I apologize if this question is too easy for you as I am just starting to learn how XML works. What I am trying to do is to append a new element to **App/Library** and for example I started with this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<App>
    <Library>
        <Count>100</Count>
        <Track>
            <TrackID>1</TrackID>
            <Name>New York</Name>
            <Artist>Snow Patrol</Name>
        </Track>
    </Library>
</App>
```

what I am trying to do is to add another track to my existing XML.

```
        <Track>
            <TrackID>2</TrackID>
            <Name>Chasing Cars</Name>
            <Artist>Snow Patrol</Name>
        </Track>
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to deal with xml manipulation in .NET.  The older style using System.Xml.XmlDocument or using System.Xml.Linq.XDocument approach.

Here is an example on how to do it using XmlDocument:

var xml = "Baz";

```
    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xml);                               //Load up the original xml string into XmlDocument object

    var fooNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//foo");    //use xpath to get to the top level foo element

    var newBar = doc.CreateElement("bar");          //Create a new bar element and assign it's inner text
    newBar.InnerText = "Baz2";

    fooNode.AppendChild(newBar);    //append the newly created bar element to foo
```

and here is an example on how to do it using XDocument (which is much more simpler):

```
var xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><foo><bar>Baz</bar></foo>";

        var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);                //Load up the original xml string into Linq XDocument object
        xdoc.Root.Add(new XElement("bar", "Bar2"));     //Add <bar>Bar2</bar> to foo (which is root of the document)
```

Here is a running example:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/vY7Vag